# Neo4j - why profiler shows only 2000003 db hits in case of fullscan of nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to understand why query profiler shows only `2000003` db hits. After all, query requires fullscan on nodes.

My question is about following query:

```
WITH ["Jennifer","Michelle","Tanya","Julie","Christie","Sophie","Amanda","Khloe","Sarah","Kaylee"] AS names 
    FOREACH (r IN range(0,1000000) | CREATE (:LabelA {username:names[r % size(names)]+r}))

WITH ["Jennifer","Michelle","Tanya","Julie","Christie","Sophie","Amanda","Khloe","Sarah","Kaylee"] AS names 
    FOREACH (r IN range(0,1000000) | CREATE (:LabelA:LabelB {username:names[r % size(names)]+r}))

WITH ["Jennifer","Michelle","Tanya","Julie","Christie","Sophie","Amanda","Khloe","Sarah","Kaylee"] AS names 
    FOREACH (r IN range(0,1000000) | CREATE (:LabelB {username:names[r % size(names)]+r}))

MATCH (n:LabelA:LabelB) RETURN COUNT(n)
```

It creates `3000003` nodes. So in order to count number of nodes with specific labels we should do full scan, so `3000003` db hits. However, profiles show that in first step it requires `2000003` db hits. How does it possible?

It is borrowed from:

https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/10/25/counting-nodes-with-multiple-labels/

Answer (score 0):

Labels are auto-indexed. This means, for labels LA and LB, that Neo4j internally has a list of all nodes with the LA label, and another list of all nodes with the LB label.

So the full scan only needs to scan those 2 indexes. And really, it only needs to scan one of them, and check each node for the second label.

Also, a 'db hit' is not actually a database read. It is actually an abstract "unit of the database's time". So treat it more like a generic measure of system IO time used. (This is more notable in complex queries with complex filters. Like sub-string matching, or finding any node.property with value 'x') (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/#execution-plans-dbhits)

Comment: Thanks for very clear answer. Could you tell me which files store these indices? Could you give more details about this index? BTree? What does it mean EagerAggregation? I mean a word Eager

Comment: @CypherFancy Indexes are a general database concept (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index). I don't know how 
 Neo4j implements it exactly, but the general idea is "create cache to improve read speed". On write, the indexes a node is a part of have to be updated (so you lose write speed), but you gain read speed (because you can use the index instead of a full scan). As for EagerAgregation, You should just read the execution plan docs (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/)